# How would I found the compound for the following on each account with compound interest?

Tags: finance

Determine how much is in each account on the basis of the indicated compounding after the specified years have passed; P is the initial principal, and r is the annual rate given as a percent. After one year where P = $4700 and r = 2.5%

Find the compound quarterly, monthly, weekly, and daily.

I found the compound annually ($4817.5) but I'm not sure what the formula would be for them. If you can explain, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For shorter compounding periods, you compute each period with the applicable interest.  For monthly compounding you get $\frac {2.5\%}{12}$ interest each month, so at the end you would have $4700(1+\frac {2.5\%}{12})^{12}$.  Compounding means you earn interest each period on the total in the account including interest earned previously.